# Water/sodium balance in diabetes insipidus

Tags: water, sodium, kidney-disease

Practitioners from my country (France) tend to classify disorders of water and sodium balance as either concerning the intracellular compartment (IC), the extracellular compartment (EC) or both. I guess that this classification of water/sodium balance disorders is not specific to France, but I did not manage to find useful references dealing with this subject in the English literature.
Assuming that the concepts of intra/extracellular over/dehydration are widely accepted, here is my question: **why is diabetes insipidus said to cause isolated intracellular dehydration?** From my understanding of the condition, people with DI do (of course) lose water in their urine, but also salt due to the limited dilution capacity of the kidneys. Because loss of salt means decrease of the osmotic pressure in the EC, the dehydration seen in people with DI should not only concern the IC, but also (I would even say predominantly) the EC.
Where am I wrong here? Thank you very much for your help.